# SUMIF Criteria Between Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have sheet Costs, and Dates the cost was raised, date cost was actually received. The cost is formatted as Currency. Planned Recieve Date is a drop down select, and Actual Goods receipt is formatted as below e.g.

```
Cost | Planned Recieve Date | Actual Goods Receipt
$XYZ | Apr-18               | 11 April 2018
$XYZ | Apr-18               | 24 April 2018
$XYZ | Apr-18               | 28 April 2018
```

What I am trying to do, is see a sum of all costs **EXPECTED** to be raised in a given month, and how much was **ACTUALLY** recieved in that given month. The Costs with dates are on one sheet "Ordering" and the formula i need is to go on another sheet.

Expected costs uses the column Planned reciept date. My formula is:

```
= SUMIF(Ordering!$L$11:$L$365, "Apr-18", Ordering!$E$11:$E$365)
```

What is giving me trouble is the Ammount actually recieved, I can't seem to figure out the criteria correctly. This uses the 'Actual Good Receipt" column, which has a formatted date. The cell displays 24 April 2018, and has 24/04/2018 in te cell editor box. The formula I've used is:

```
= SUMIF(Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,">=01/04/2018 AND <=30/04/2018",Ordering!$M$11:$M$365)
```

This gives me a value BELOW what I expect, and im missing no costs. (only have 3 for the omnth of april.) I have tried multiple different ways of writing my Criteria, and I have used wildcards.

What is the correct way to construct my criteria so that I can see total cost of the ACTUAL RECIEVED for all dates within a given month?

Comment: Could you share some sample data with us to fix the issue in better way !! ☺

Comment: Your 2nd formula should written like this, = `SUMIFS(Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,">=01/04/2018 ,Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,<=30/04/2018",Ordering!$M$11:$M$365)`

Comment: And, should you ever want to use `AND` in the future, the proper syntax is `AND(Condition1, Condition2, Condition3,...)`

Comment: @RajeshS SUMIFS order is different.  The Sum range should be first not last: `=SUMIFS(Ordering!$M$11:$M$365,Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,">=01/04/2018 ,Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,<=30/04/2018")`

Comment: @ScottCraner,, Yes U are write ,, it's my mistake. **Readers plzz read it like this**,,, `=SUMIFS(Ordering!$M$11:$M$365,Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,">=01/04/2018 ,Ordering!$P$11:$P$365,<=30/04/2018")`. Basically my prime reason was to alerts OP use `SUMIFS` instead of  `SUMIF`.

Comment: SUMIFS Was the way forward. Thank you for the tip off, @Rajesh S

Comment: @RajeshS and Scott Craner I think you are both missing a " before the last date criteria  <=30/04/2018".  Additionally if you wind up sending this spreadsheet to other systems where the system date is in a different order, ie yy/mm/dd, then you may want to consider changing your criteria from hard coded to a cell with the date entered in it or "<="&DATE(2018,04,30)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Sumproduct formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A10)=4)*(MONTH(A2:A10)=4), (B2:B10))
```

- A2:A10 is a range of your dates;
- 4 is number of month (april);
- B2:B10 is a range where your prices are

Comment: This formula will work fine until the Dates are between `01/04/2018` and `30/04/2018` but when its change to `01/04/2018` and `17/04/2018` will create problem. My suggestion is better use the `Dates` instead of `Month`. ☺

Comment: of course dates will work better, but the question was "for all dates within a given month?"

Answer (score 1):

#### Hardcoding the formula

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">=01/04/18",A2:A10,"<=30/04/18")
```

#### Option 1 - Manually Entering Date into Formula

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">="&DATE(2018,4,1),A2:A10,"<="&DATE(2018,4,30))
```

#### Option 2 - Referencing a date in a cell

```
Start Date in G1
End Date in G2

=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">="&$G$1,A2:A10,"<="&$G$2)
```

#### Option 3 - Returning a 1 month period based the month in a cell reference

```
Date reference in G1

=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,">="&EOMONTH($G$1,-1)+1,A2:A10,"<="&EOMONTH($G$1,0))
```

Comment: updated Option 3 formula.  not sure what was running through my head when I typed it out the first time.